# why does this code only delete books with one word names

Tags: php, mysqli

For some reason when i call this deletebook.php the query is always true but it will only actually delete the book if the name has one word in it. Any suggestions ive been pretty stuck for a bit and could use some help.

```
    $book = $_GET["book"];
    $email = $_SESSION["email"];

    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    // sql to delete a record
    $sql = "DELETE FROM books WHERE email = '". $email ."' and name = '". $book ."'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record deleted successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();



?>
```

This is the related code from managebooks.php

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo    "<div id='book'>
                <ol>
                <li>"; 
            echo    $row['name'];
            echo    "</li><li>";
            echo    $row['price'];
            echo    "</li>
                </ol>
                <form action='deleteBook.php' method='get'>
                <input type='hidden' name='book' value=". $row['name'] ." />
                <button type='submit'>Delete</button></form></div>";

        }
```

Comment: Quote the value? `value='". $row['name'] ."' />`

Comment: you really should have id's and use them for this kind of thing

Comment: also I suggest you to test your code with book name contain `'` and `"`, for example my favorite book name is `'"><script>alert();</script>`

Comment: Thanks abra cadaver! i feel silly now

Comment: bah the bottom feeders are busy today

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the value of "value" in quotes. Also, try using a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) when echoing multiple lines of html; it makes figuring out quotes easier.
(It's also best practice to double-quote all values of all HTML attributes.)

Answer (score -1):

I think you should make your sql string cleaner it may help

```
$sql="DELETE FROM books WHERE email='$email' AND name='$book'";
```

You can also print out the value of $name to actually see what is being sent to the $sql string